# Add two button for each item in flatlist

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Actually i'm working for a school project in react native and i want to know if it's possible to add two buttons into flatlist using react-native.

```
export class ItineraryScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data:[
                {key: 'PKRX'},
                {key: 'UXUA'},
                {key: 'PGRF'},
            ]
    };
}

render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
                    />
            </ScrollView>
        );


}
```

could you give some advices to implement this feature please?

Best regards,

Imad.

Comment: Create a component with your text and your buttons and put it in the `renderItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how yu could do it ([Repro on Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@gasshette/bold-truffles)) :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet , FlatList, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const data = [
                {key: 'PKRX'},
                {key: 'UXUA'},
                {key: 'PGRF'},
            ];

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={data} renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} /> } />
    </View>
  );
}

const Item = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{item.key}</Text>
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}>
        <Butto title='Button 1' onPress={() => {}} />
        <Button title='Button 2' onPress={() => {}} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```